# Should I underscore prefix all non-API members in Python?

Tags: python, interface, prefix, pep8

So the underscore prefix for methods and attributes is rarely used in Python. But it is very convenient to make clear which methods are part of the API. This has the advantage of being self explanatory and making refactoring a lot safer, as it is a warning and gives the responsibility to the other programmer when accessing/overwriting those members. But around 80% of the methods and attributes would be prefixed then, and again, it is rarely used in other libraries, looks ugly, and feels unpythonic to me.

I am programming in Python for 4 years, and almost never used the underscore prefix for the above reasons, and I'm not a control freak, but start thinking about it for the above reasons for a cleaner interface description. PEP8 does not discourage its use.

So what should I do now, should I prefix *all* my non-API members with underscores?

Comment: This is a "coding style" question. There is no objective answer. [PEP8 provides some examples and guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Comment: I know the underscore related parts of PEP8, and couldn't find any further hints about it apart from that it is *possible*. If it is a coding style question, my question refers to why this coding style is so infamous. I searched a lot on this topic before posting the question on SO, and everywhere it says "possible", "useful", but actually it is not used that much.

Comment: So then you are free to do as you (or senior developer or project lead/author/maintainer) wishes. Be consistent (within each project) and be able to justify rational behind decisions.

Answer (score 2):

As [this popular interpretation](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) of `import this` goes;

`joined_lowercase` for attributes, methods, and functions

`joined_lowercase or JOINED_CAPS` for constants

`ThisKindOfCamelCase` for classes

To be more specific, attributes can be `interface`, `_internal`, or `__private`,

> But try to avoid the __private form. I never use it. Trust me. If you use it, you **WILL** regret it later.

Comment: I know they *can* be indicated as being ``_internal``, and this is not my question. I ask if I really should *do* it extensively.

Comment: Yes! It makes your code easier to read.

Comment: So why is it used so inconsequentially for internal members in up to date and professional libraries like Django, Tastypie, Sphinx, … ?

Comment: That's because it's their _style_. How you name your attributes is merely a question of style; I can only give you popular recommendation. The only real "rule" is that you try to be _consistent_ with your style.

Comment: I appreciate your answers ... but as the prefix has the function to indicate the privacy of an attribute, it is no only about *style* from my point of view, but also about good programming practice or "the best way to do it".

Comment: The best way to do it is to make things clear. If something's not in the API, just underscore-prefix it, and at the beginning, just briefly note how everything not in the API is prefixed by an underscore. The rule is to be consistent with your style.

Comment: @Iodnas: I suspect that the reason most people don't use it is because they're lazy and to do so requires more thought, simple as that. I think of it as way to adding information that users of class may find useful, as well as to anyone (including myself) who modifies or subclasses the class later.

Comment: Double underscore is special. It activates name mangling. Don't use it unless you _need_ name mangling.